# How about a `macOS` tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got an `osx` tag and an `mac` tag. The Emacs community is nothing if not pedantic `;)`, and Apple renamed it to `macOS` in 2016, so why not a fold them both into a singular `macOS` tag?

Comment: `macOS` is better than `osx` and `mac` IMO.